# rowTemplate for Kendo Angular 2 grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

According to https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/faq/ Kendo Grid for Angular 2 supports Row Templates

> **Does the Grid for Angular support the same attributes, such as header
>   attributes and row templates, as the Grid for jQuery?**
>
> Yes, it does. For more information, refer to the [API index of the Grid.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/)

However, looking at the API and the examples, I can't find a rowTemplate example anywhere. I need to add a directive to the row for a row level tooltip. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that row template exists.
But you probably want cell template. Demo can be found under [Columns Templates](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-cell-template).

[This plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qEwR483ytkH6Tv9TNokX?p=preview) is showing hint on cell value.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <strong [title]="dataItem.Discontinued ? 'discontinued' : 'active'">{{dataItem.ProductName}}</strong>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: I have a requirement for the tooltip to appear whenever you hover over any part of the row.

At the minute, I have duplicated the tooltip with a column template for each field but it's not ideal! I can imagine other scenarios where you'd want to add directives at row level too. I'll raise it as a suggestion with kendo as it doesn't seem to be possible despite what the documentation says